# Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap

Tags: jboss, resteasy, restful-url

i am new to restful services.When i run my project its giving me the 
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTeasy Provider Factory is null, do you have the ResteasyBootstrap listener configured?

web.xml

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
        </listener>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
        </listener>
<context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/api</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
            </servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/webresource/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```